# Bring to Button front while having two ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, z-order

I'm trying to implement the following design on Android.

[image: Android Screen]

I know that to have the button at that position I should have two constraint layout; one for whole change password form and one for change password form without the Save button and then set the Save button's `Top` and `Bottom` constraint to the second ConstraintLayout.
But when I do this, the button goes behind the form, and therein lies the problem:

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ChangePasswordActivity">
    
        <include
            android:id="@+id/changePasswordBar"
            layout="@layout/top_bar_full"></include>
    
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/changePasswordCTL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activities_constraint_top_bottom"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activities_constraint_start_end"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activities_constraint_start_end"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activities_constraint_top_bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_background_exchange"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                // some EditText and TextView views here
    
    
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <br.com.simplepass.loading_button_lib.customViews.CircularProgressButton
                android:id="@+id/changePasswordBT"
                style="@style/customButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sans_web_medium"
                android:text="@string/finish"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/signinup_button_font_size"
                app:initialCornerAngle="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/changePasswordCTL"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/changePasswordCTL"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/changePasswordCTL"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changePasswordCTL"
                app:spinning_bar_color="@android:color/white"
                app:spinning_bar_padding="6dp"
                app:spinning_bar_width="4dp" />
    
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Is the password field a `CardView`? Is the finish button a `Button`?

Comment: @BenP. password field is EditText and the Button is a custom library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `elevation` isn't in the picture, views that are defined later in the XML file will draw "on top" of views defined earlier. However, your password form has `android:elevation="5dp"`, and this will override the normal drawing order.

To fix, add elevation to the button as well. `android:elevation="5dp"` should be enough, since then they're at the same elevation and the normal rules should apply. But you could give it more elevation to guarantee that it always draws on top of the password form.

Answer (score 5):

There is a `5dp` elevation on the form and no elevation on the button, so it is partially obscured. Increase the button elevation to at least `5dp`.

```
android:elevation="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve such design by using a CoordinatorLayout.

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/primary" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/header"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

just use the following to anchor the layout of your button to the layout of your library view:

```
app:layout_anchor= "id_of_password_form_layout"
```